# Get a HTML5 video to play once on page load and then fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a HTML5 clip to play only **once** on first arrival/pageload to the home page and then not play again. Also I would like the video to **fadeout** and disappear after it's played. I know you can do this with JQuery once and fadeout, but I'm a beginner and I am struggling with the syntax. Can a more experienced coder help me adjust my code so this works please? Here's what I have so far!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#video").one("load", function(){
$('#video').get(0).play()
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a website</h2>

<video id="video">
<source src="clip.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

OP requests that the state of the video is persistent. I suggested cookies or `localStorage`. The following update is hosted on [<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/tDIuWdIWdNjnsTKim6jw/) but not on the Snippet because there's strict security measures that are inhibiting the use of `localStorage`.

There's a basic flow to the demonstration you should adhere to initially:

1. Upon initial page load, the video plays and the console says:

   > **Cache set to: played**
2. After the video has ended and faded out, reload the page. Notice that the video is no longer present nor is it playing. The console now says:

   > **Cache is: played**
3. Reload the page several times and it will not change.
4. Should you have the need to revert the page back to it's original state, I have added a <kbd>Delete Cache</kbd> button that deletes that specific key that stores the information responsible for keeping the page at the state of post video playback.
5. Once the <kbd>Delete Cache</kbd> button is clicked, the console should say:

   > **undefined**

This means that the **cache** was successfully deleted. Details are commented within the [<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/tDIuWdIWdNjnsTKim6jw/)

---

Create a `<video>` dynamically and remove it from the DOM on the `ended` event. Details commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Create and reference video element
var vid = document.createElement('video');

// Add class for styling
vid.classList.add('playing');

// Add a src to .vid
vid.src = 'http://media6000.dropshots.com/photos/1381926/20170326/023642.mp4';

// Load .vid
vid.load();

// Add .vid to body
document.body.appendChild(vid);

// Play video
vid.play();

/* Register ended event to vid
|| After video has ended...
*/
vid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {

  // Pause vid
  vid.pause()

  /* Reset time played. This method used
  || along with .pause() is equivelant to "stop"
  */
  vid.currentTime = 0;

  // Simulate a `non-playing state`
  vid.classList.remove('playing');

  /* Delay the call to remove vid in order
  || to preserve the fade ouyt effect.
  */
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.body.removeChild(vid);
  }, 2000);
}, false);
```

```css
video.playing {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 3s ease;
}

video {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s ease;
}
```

Comment: zer00ne, interesting, does your code make the video only ever run once per website visit as well? as that's the goal, to run once and then fade out to invisible.

Comment: Once as in per session? Or once until your browser is cleaned? It is like the jQuery method `one()` as you described in your question. If you want a persistent behavior, then cookies or localStorage is needed as well.

Comment: Once per entire visit to the site - Yes cookies or local storage, something for me to read up on in the future. Thanks for your post zer00ne

Comment: zer00ne, the plunker that you did that plays the video just once and then fades out looks excellent, well done on that.

Comment: @watchglass49 Thank you, sir. If you want to reset the state back to original, just click the `Delete Cache` button. If this has resolved your question, check the ✔ of this post. Happy coding.

Comment: Yes it has resolved the question thanks zer00ne, I clicked up but it won't record my vote yet as I don't have a 15 score.

Comment: No worries, you'll have voting powers soon, your question is better than most OP at 100+

Answer (score 0):

You can use html "autoplay" property to play video once page loaded as here.

```
<div id="video">
<video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="monarch.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="monarch.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
</video>
</div>
```

then use jquery to to fade out the vedio after play as below,

```
$('#video video').bind('ended', function(){
   $(this).parent().fadeOut()
});
```

Created a fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/ddukpcbd/1/
Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks for your input techhunter, I got your code working but only when I put the jquery in the body section of the html page, it did not work when the code was in the head section for some reason.

Comment: Before above jquery add $.(document).on(ready,function (){//above jquery code });

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this in a different way:

index.html is the video clip, after the video is ended I used this code below to make the video disappear and move onto the home page which is home.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="9;url=home.html"
```

Included in index.html are 2 javascript if statements, to redirect immediately to home.html if the screen width is less than 600 pixels, because mobile phones won't autoplay videos. 2 similar if statements were used to ensure the if statements worked in as many browsers as possible. Below are the if statements used:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 600) {
window.location = "home.html";
}
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (window.innerWidth <= 600) {
document.location = "home.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

Originally I asked the question because I wanted the video to play only **once** per entire visit to the website and keep the video in the same html page as the home page, rather than a different page as I have now. Jquery **one** would not have achieved this, as that would have made the video play once per page load, not once per website visit. However other methods like session cookies or javascript session storage could have kept this video feature in the same page. But this solution resolved the issue well and simply so I used that method.

To further improve this, I added an event listener on to only move onto the next page when the video was ended, not at 9 seconds like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="9;url=home.html"
```

but only when ended (incase the browser is slow to load and 9 seconds is not enough)

```
<script>
video=document.getElementById('myvid').addEventListener('ended',function(){
window.location.href='home.html';
});
</script>
```

The Javascript above assumes the video has an id="myvid"